# Excel VBA to Uppercase

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, uppercase

Can someone tell me if the following code is optimized and correct for Excel VBA to Uppercase on cell focus?

Sometime it slows the Excel. Could there be a better version?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
 
 For Each cell In Target
     If IsEmpty(cell) Then
  
    
 ElseIf cell.HasFormula = True Then
  
       cell.Font.Name = "Arial Narrow"
    cell.Font.Size = 9
    Else

    cell = UCase(cell)
    cell.Font.Name = "Arial Narrow"
    cell.Font.Size = 9
        End If
    
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: On focus (selecting a different cell/range) or on change (cell contents are updated)?  `Worksheet_change` event is not triggered by changes due to formulas recalculating.

Comment: Running VBA on every change will certainly slow down Excel. It would be better to have a formatting macro that you run on save to correct everything at once.

Comment: Never repeat an equal assignment! 
Put cell.Font.Name = "Arial Narrow" before  For Each cell In Target and don't repeat it. 
Same goes with cell.Font.Size = 9

Comment: FYI the question isn't necessarily off-topic here (although arguably a bit broader than typical), but with a title like "Forcing uppercase in modified cells", this would make a very fine, well-received post on [codereview.se], where the "questions" are *specifically* asking for feedback on any/all aspects of the code that's put up for peer review.

Comment: NOTED!THANKS TO ALL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indentation is inconsistent, repeated statements can be reorganized so that no repetition is needed; empty code blocks shouldn't need to exist, a conditional expression that compares a `Boolean` expression to a `Boolean` literal is redundant, and implicit default member calls can be made explicit for clearer code:

```vb
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Target
    If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
        If Not cell.HasFormula Then
            cell.Value = UCase(cell.Value)
        End If
        cell.Font.Name = "Arial Narrow"
        cell.Font.Size = 9
    End If
Next
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

[Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) (free, open-source; I manage the project) could help with indentation, and its code inspections would have warned about the empty block (and suggested inverting the conditional) and the implicit default member calls against `Range` (`cell.Value`).

As for performance, being a `Worksheet.Change` event handler means the macro iterates every modified cell every time any cell is modified. Most of the time that would be for a single cell, so the loop only iterates once most of the time; you could probably earn a few milliseconds by disabling `ScreenUpdating` and setting the  `Calculation` mode to `xlCalculationManual` along with the `EnableEvents` being set to `True`, but IMO the benefits would be marginal.

Consider using styles instead of setting individual cells' `Font.Name` and `Font.Size`, but the most impactful modification to do here would be to test `Target` for intersection with a particular specific interesting `Range` of cells on the worksheet - for example if you wanted to only run that loop if the `Target` is inside the `A2:C25` range, you could have this test as the first thing the macro does, to prevent executing any code when the modified cell is outside that range:

```
If Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A2:C25") Is Nothing Then
    'modified cell isn't in A2:C25; bail out
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Note that a `Worksheet.Change` event handler procedure does not run "on cell *focus*", but "on cell value/formula *modified*"; look into handling `Worksheet.SelectionChange` instead, to run code whenever a cell aquires Excel's selection rectangle.